# Некорректно отображается CheckBox на старых Android API

Tags: android, checkbox, ui

В старых Andoid API (как минимум на API 19) поставленные в CheckBox флажки не видны, но после нажатия *checked* становится равным *true*. Прикрепляю скриншоты

**API 19:**

[image]

**API 22:**

[image]

**XML-код CheckBox'а:**

```
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Доктор"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxDoctor"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextCntMafia"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonBack"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonBack"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать класс AppCompatCheckBox:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatCheckBox.html

Comment: при использовагии темы appcompat чекбоксы должны без постороннего участия подменятся на чекбоксы из библиотеки

Comment: android:buttonTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"    эта строчка косвенно указывает на то что скорее всего используется не appcompat тема, а holo